# Shell script entire into sub directory and perform command action based on array

Tags: bash

1. I have below script to entre into each directory based on startdir as input path
2. Then it assign the value of startdir into for loop (dir)
3. Then I'm changing directory to (dir) which mentioned in step 2.
4. Then I have another for loop to entre into each subdirectory (subdir)

Now the question I want to entre into each subfolder (A, B, C, D) and need make zip file inside the current directory zip file name should be based on current working directory.

```
+ startdir=("/workspace/input/data")
+ for dir in "${startdir[@]}"
+ cd /workspace/input/data
+ for subdir in */
+ ls -lrt
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 C
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 D
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 A
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 B
+ zip -r A.zip .
  adding: B/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B/b.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: D/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/a.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: C/ (stored 0%)
+ for subdir in */
+ ls -lrt
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 C
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 D
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 A
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 B
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  834 Jun  5 16:35 A.zip
+ zip -r B.zip .
  adding: A.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: B/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B/b.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: D/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/a.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: C/ (stored 0%)
+ for subdir in */
+ ls -lrt
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 C
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 D
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 A
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 B
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1806 Jun  5 16:35 B.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  834 Jun  5 16:35 A.zip
+ zip -r C.zip .
  adding: A.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: B/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B/b.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: D/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/a.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: C/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B.zip (stored 0%)
+ for subdir in */
+ ls -lrt
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 C
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:33 D
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 A
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  5 16:34 B
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3750 Jun  5 16:35 C.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1806 Jun  5 16:35 B.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  834 Jun  5 16:35 A.zip
+ zip -r D.zip .
  adding: A.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: C.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: B/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B/b.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: D/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/a.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: C/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B.zip (stored 0%)
```

```
#!/bin/bash

startdir=(
  "/workspace/input/data"
)

for dir in "${startdir[@]}"; do
(
  cd "$dir" || continue
  for subdir in */; do
  ls -lrt
    zip -r "${subdir%/}.zip" .
  done
)
done
```

correct me what 'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Put a `set -x´ in your script for debugging. In Particular your `zip` command looks weird to me. In any case, after having the trace, point out which line does not produce the desired result.

Comment: sorry for the trouble iIhave updated

Comment: `zip -r "${subdir%/}.zip" .` why do you zip `.` and not `zip "${subdir}"`?

Comment: As you now see from your trace, you are also adding the previously created zip files into your new zip file. This does not make sense. Also, your `A.zip` already contains all subdirectories. Why then do you also need a B.zip etc.?

Comment: See i want to entre into directory A then i need to create zip a.txt and then same B then b.txt

Comment: Hi @user1934428 current script creating zip file based on the directory A, But now the thing instead of taking A directory as zip, i need change the directory inside  A and take only those files which is present inside the directory.

Comment: Then nobody keeps you from doing this! To enter a directory, do a `cd "$subdir"`, and to go back where you came from, do a `cd -`.

Comment: I’d add that the `cd -` trick only has 1 level of history. In case an entire stack is needed, `pushd` and `popd` may be a better option. (They print out the current directory stack each time and are not limited to a single previously visited directory.) However, the question sounds like only one level of directory traversal is needed, so it likely doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing into the directory you want to pack.

Change your zip line to:

```
zip -r "${subdir%/}.zip" ${subdir}
```

now it will not pack the current directory (everything) but it will pack only the directory matching with the subdir name.

output:

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  180 jun  5 14:37 script.sh
  adding: A/ (stored 0%)
  adding: A/file.txt (stored 0%)
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  180 jun  5 14:37 script.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  304 jun  5 14:41 A.zip
  adding: B/ (stored 0%)
  adding: B/file.txt (stored 0%)
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  180 jun  5 14:37 script.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  304 jun  5 14:41 A.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  304 jun  5 14:41 B.zip
  adding: C/ (stored 0%)
  adding: C/file.txt (stored 0%)
```

ls of the dir:

```
A  A.zip  B  B.zip  C  C.zip  script.sh
```

Another way of doing it if you don't want the directory in the zip is:

```
cd ${subdir}
zip -r "../${subdir%/}.zip" .
cd ..
```

Now you only have the files in the directory in the zip.

output:

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  202 jun  5 14:44 script.sh
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%) 
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  202 jun  5 14:44 script.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  168 jun  5 14:44 A.zip
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%) 
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  5 14:36 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  202 jun  5 14:44 script.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  168 jun  5 14:44 A.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  168 jun  5 14:44 B.zip
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%)
```